# Как сохранить таблицы одной базы данных в MySQL и перенести в другую?

Tags: база-данных, dump, mysql

Имеется две базы данных (database) в MySQL. Названия у них разные, но структура таблиц одинаковая. Как сделать бэкап одной базы и залить данные в другую? Пожалуйста, с описанием команд, что и как. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysqldump -u <user> -p<password> <db1> | mysql -u <user> -p<password> <db2>
```

Первая команда — mysqldump. Собственно, она выводит содержимой указанной базы данных в виде текста.
Вторая команда — банально читает из стандартного потока дамп (в том же формате, в котором его выдаёт mysqldump, что удобно!) и заливает его в указанную БД.

Соответственно, сцепили их конвейером — и всё получилось. Можно через промежуточный файл, если больше нравится.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё идея на всякий случай.

Есть такой секретный синтаксис (никому о нём не рассказывайте!):

```sql
CREATE TABLE <new_table> AS SELECT * FROM <old_table>;
```

Если помнить, что имена таблиц можно указывать в виде `имя_БД.имя_таблицы`, то таким образом несложно перенести одну таблицу в другую БД.

Однако, тут не получится перенести все таблицы за один ход. Боюсь, что без хранимых процедур, на чистом SQL, эта задача не имеет решения.